# Express-Pouchdb + fauxton on non root route

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, couchdb, pouchdb

If I run pouch on "/" route, I can go to /_utils and use fauxton, but if I change to non root, ex. "/db" route, fauxton will stop working.  Is there a work around to make fauxton work on non-root.

In my web app, I want to make express-pouchdb on "/db" route, superlogin on "/auth" and my webapp on "/" route.  This way I can run a small webapp, that has a backend that syncs with my mobile app running on one instance of node.  This can potently work on heroku and other free/cheap node hosting providers. Its a great starting point for small app, and once the app grows, its easy to connect to couchdb.